# ¿java hacer un ciclo que calcule la sumotaria del 0 al 10; y el numero máximo sea 30?

Tags: java, bucle-for

Mediante un ciclo necesito hacer la sumatoria del 0 al 10; y llegar al máximo de numero que es al 30.
¿como sumar estos números 0,2,4,6,8,10 mediante el for?

```
  int inicio = 0;
int limite = 30;
int incremento = 0;



incremento++;
```

for (int i=inicio; i <=30; i+=incremento*2)

```
System.out.println (i);
```

Comment: Si lo que deseas es iterar del 0 al 10 con paso 2: `for(int i=0;i<=10;i+=2)`, esto contempla sólo `0,2,4,6,8,10`. Además, si deseas obtener la suma de estos números, deberás inicializar en 0 una variable de tipo entero antes del for (por ejemplo: `int suma=0;`), luego dentro del for, irás incrementándola: `suma+=i`.

Comment: Ok voy a revisarlo.

Comment: @Firefly publica ese comentario como respuesta, es totalmente válida. Claro, debes darle un poco más de contexto, ;). Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo único que tenías mal es que estabas haciendo una multiplicación * 2 que no era necesaria.

```
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int limite = 30;
    int incremento = 2;
    int inicio = 0;
    int sumatoria = 0;
    for (int numero = inicio; numero <= limite; numero = numero + incremento) {
      sumatoria += numero;
      System.out.print(numero + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("La sumatoria es: " + sumatoria);
  }
}
```

Si posteriormente quieres imprimir cualquier secuencia puedes crear un método aparte de manera que funcione para cualquier limite, inicio y fin que tú indiques.

```
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("La sumatoria es: " +  imprimirSecuencia(30, 2, 0));
  }

  public static int imprimirSecuencia(int limite, int incremento, int inicio) {
    int sumatoria = 0;
    for (int numero = inicio; numero <= limite; numero = numero + incremento) {
      sumatoria += numero;
      System.out.print(numero + " ");
    }
  return sumatoria;
  }
}
```

Comment: Excelente gracias, voy revisarlo de nuevo.

Comment: De nada, aquí estamos si es que algo no funcionó como esperabas o si tienes dudas.

Comment: Excelente gracias.

Comment: ¿Pero se tiene que crear otro for o solo con uno se puede hacer la suma de esos números y llegar al limite a 30?

Comment: He añadido el código para calcular la sumatoria.

Comment: Ok esta bien gracias.